# Voltage drop reason not understood

Tags: power-supply, voltage, switch-mode-power-supply, load

I am using a 12V 5A adaptor to power a 12V pump and a 12V solenoid valve. The solenoid valve is supposed to pull 600mA, the pump is supposed to pull 0.6-1A. Hence to play safe the 12V 5A adaptor. Besides this I am also powering my Arduino with the same supply and a buck convertor converting to 5V in between. The Arduino is loaded not much, just a 16x2 LCD, a sensor drawing about 20mA, a relay module (single channel, not always live.)

I am seeing a voltage drop to 10V each time the pump and solenoid valve are powered. I was specifically advised that the ampere rating of the adaptor should be more than double the expected load to prevent a voltage drop, hence my 5A adaptor, but the voltage drop is still there, and the output of pump is going down. Now to my mind either the pump is dying or the adaptor was never fully alive as the flow through the pump has gone down. What is the issue here?

[image]

Comment: How long and what kind of cable do you have?  Pumps etc often are at longer distance.

Comment: How long is the wire? Where are you measuring the 10V? A 2V drop across a long wire at 1A+ isn't that surprising. Measure the resistance of the wire to be sure.

Comment: @jonathanjo not very long cables, 50cm at most between the adaptor and the pump, its a small confined machine.

Comment: @Puffafish I am feeding the supply from the adaptor into a breadboard side rails, and from the siderails to the adaptor. I am measuring the voltage in the siderails.

Comment: How do you know the pump does not take 10A momentarily when it starts? Have you added any capacitance to your circuit to help with drop? Do you have a data sheet for your power supply? It might be normal for that power supply to react slowly to loads. If the pump takes a large initial surge current, the power supply may momentarily be limited to 5A or hit a overcurrent protection limit. Ok, a breadboard; can it handle that current?

Comment: @Justme it didn't occur to me that it could draw ten times the current rating. I was told twice should be safe expectation. This is the pump I am using https://www.amazon.in/QBM-Solar-Water-Cooler-Black/dp/B0B461CLYQ/ref=b2b_gw_d_simh_sccl_1/257-0063603-3003310?pd_rd_w=8icjd&content-id=amzn1.sym.51df10ec-036c-4582-a6dd-e698821da553&pf_rd_p=51df10ec-036c-4582-a6dd-e698821da553&pf_rd_r=0Z20P62DZAJ2D20AHH02&pd_rd_wg=QeZ9J&pd_rd_r=39ae82a3-29a3-40d1-ac25-bbf027f8e718&pd_rd_i=B0B461CLYQ&psc=1 .The power supply is a cheap one, don't think can find datasheet for it either.

Comment: In my experience. "No datasheet" = "Expect surprises" :-)

Comment: Do not use breadboard side rails to take amps of current, there's your voltage drop.

Comment: Put a 1000uF electrolyte cap on the supply input of your board. Oh and do not use breadboards at all, for any purpose. It is useless trash. Solder all components.

Comment: @Lundin got it, thanks

Comment: So soldering everything and bypassing the breadboard siderails and adding capacitor didn't resolve it. Voltage drop still happening. Pump acting like its on its death bed, flow rate is terribly low now.

Comment: Can you measure the current that pump takes on startup? When running? Run it from a 12 V car battery for testing, they tend to be able to deliver any current they're asked to, well, up to a few 100 amps anyway.

Comment: @Neil_UK I get it but can't think of where I can get a car battery. I thought maybe it could happen if I had connected the pump and solenoid in series, but just checked and they both have independent connection to the +ve and -Ve, so definitely in parallel. I am switching the system on the -Ve terminal, could that have an effect? Flyback diodes are in place

Comment: Could you add a schematic, or a clear picture of your whole setup?  Do you have a resistor or some other load that can draw the current you expect the pump to draw?  If the supply cant push a couple amps through the resistor you know it's the problem.
Just curious what is the solenoid used for?

Answer (score 3):

> I am feeding the supply from the adaptor into a breadboard side rails, and from the siderails to the adaptor. I am measuring the voltage in the siderails.

There's your problem.  The rails of a solderless breadboard aren't made to carry high current.

The sockets have relatively high resistance and the rails themselves aren't very thick - and they aren't made of copper.

As far as the pump is concerned, your breadboard is essentially a resistor between it and the power supply.

Wire the pump directly to the relay and the power supply instead of running it through the breadboard.

Comment: aha, could never have thought of that, thanks...will solder everything...if  the problem persists then will write again...

Comment: hey, I soldered everything, but the voltage drop is still there, and my pump's flow rate is consistently decreasing, like its on its deathbed